# GraphQL nested resolvers

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I'm new to GraphQL and I'm trying to set up a demo app to give a little introductory talk to my colleagues.

**I'm working with NodeJS.**

I've come up with the following schema:

```
type Query {
  author(id:Int!): Author
  song(id:Int!): Song
}
type Author {
  id:Int!
  name:String!
  songs(max:Int):[Song]!
}
type Song {
  id:Int!
  name:String!
  author:Author!
}
```

And this is the part of the resolvers relevant to the Song.author association:

```
[...]
Song: {
  author: ({ id }, args, context, info) => {
    return mergeInfo.delegate(
      'query',
      'author',
      { id },
      context,
      info,
    );
  }
}
[...]
```

So the problem with this approach is that I need to add the Song.id to the containing query to be able to include the Song.author in it:

```
{
  song(id: 1) {
    id
    author {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

The following would not work:

```
{
  song(id: 1) {
    author {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Depending on the implementation it would give me an error or `null` (that would be even worse).

This forces who writes the query to know the implementation details of the back-end and this is obviously bad. :P

**Does anyone have any solution to this issue? Is there anything that I overlooked?**

I've tried using the `info` object, but this would solve the problem just because the id I need is part of the query, but I could come up with a scenario in which the param that I need is in the data available only in the back-end.

**UPDATE:**

As requested by Daniel (thanks), this is the whole test file that creates the schema including the stitching:

```
const { makeExecutableSchema, mergeSchemas } = require('graphql-tools');

const DATA = {
  authors: {
    1: { id: 1, name: 'John' },
    2: { id: 2, name: 'Paul' },
  },
  songs: {
    1: { id: 1, name: 'Love me do', authorId: 1 },
    2: { id: 2, name: 'I wanna be your man', authorId: 1 },
    3: { id: 3, name: 'I\'ll be back', authorId: 2 },
  }
};

const authorsTypes = `
  type Query {
    author(id:Int!): Author
  }
  type Author {
    id:Int!
    name:String!
  }
`;
const authorSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: authorsTypes,
  resolvers: {
    Query: {
      author: (_, { id }) => DATA.authors[id],
    },
  },
});
const authorsLinksTypes = `
  extend type Author {
    songs(max:Int):[Song]!
  }
`;
const authorsLinksResolvers = mergeInfo => ({
  Author: {
    songs: ({ id }, args, context, info) => {
      return Object.values(DATA.songs).filter(it => it.authorId === id)
    }
  },
});

const songsTypes = `
  type Query {
    song(id:Int!): Song
  }
  type Song {
    id:Int!
    name:String!
  }
`;
const songsSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: songsTypes,
  resolvers: {
    Query: {
      song: (_, { id }) => DATA.songs[id],
    },
  },
});
const songsLinksTypes = `
  extend type Song {
    author:Author!
  }
`;
const songsLinksResolvers = mergeInfo => ({
  Song: {
    author: ({ id }, args, context, info) => {
      return mergeInfo.delegate(
        'query',
        'author',
        { id },
        context,
        info,
      );
    }
  },
});

module.exports = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: [authorSchema, songsSchema, songsLinksTypes, authorsLinksTypes],
  resolvers: mergeInfo => ({
    ...songsLinksResolvers(mergeInfo),
    ...authorsLinksResolvers(mergeInfo),
  }),
});
```

Comment: Can you include your song query resolver? Also, if you're doing schema stitching, it would be helpful to include those details in your question.

Comment: I would recommend to not use Schema stitching for a demo. Schema stitching is used for rather large scale apps (e.g. microservices at IBM). 100+ types should be easily maintainable without it. Even then stitching is only one solution, some companies generate their types from the services behind it. If you want to keep some things separate have a look at graphcool/import-schema

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll definitely not use stitching for the demo

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle this would be to utilize context to pass down the song id. That means you would need to modify the resolver for the `song` query like this:

```
Query: {
  song: (_, { id }, context) => {
    context.songId = id
    return DATA.songs[id]
  },
},
```

and then you can grab the id from the context inside your author resolver

```
Song: {
  author: (song, args, context, info) => {
    const id = song.id || context.songId
    return mergeInfo.delegate(
      'query',
      'author',
      { id },
      context,
      info,
    );
  }
},
```

Comment: Wow, can you just change the context like that? Great

Comment: I've got a problem by the way... What's up when you have collections?If you create a more nested query it's really hard to keep track of which is the parent/containing object of a certain resolver...

Comment: You are not supposed to modify the context like that. See the following passage: "As a best practice, context should be the same for all resolvers, no matter the particular query or mutation, and resolvers should never modify it. This ensures consistency across resolvers, and helps increase development velocity." from https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/essentials/data#context